# How to parse jquery using bash or perl

Tags: jquery, python, parsing, sed, awk

I'm trying to parse jquery code like this: (this is a major portion, but NOT all of it)

```
$("#column-wide").css({"background-color":"#eff6f9"});
$("#2626").css({"width":"300px"});
$("#2627").css({"width":"300px"});
$("#2628").css({"width":"300px"});
$("#2629").css({"width":"300px"});
$(".Country > label").css({"position":"relative", "left":"-20px", "top":0});
$("#2631").css({"position":"relative", "left":"-20px", "top":0, "width":128,   "height":29});
$("#2633").css({"width":"300px"});
$("#2634").css({"width":"300px"});
// CONTACT INFO BELOW: 
$("#2633").css({});
$("#2633").css({"position":"relative", "left":0, "top":0, "width":289, "height":19});
$("#2630").css({"position":"relative", "left":0, "top":0, "width":46, "height":19});
$("#2638").css({"width":"300px"});
$("#2639").css({"width":"300px"});
$(".Prefix").css({"display":"none", "visibility":""});
$(".Last_Name").css({"left":39, "top":3});
$("#2636").css({"position":"relative", "left":49, "top":1});
$("#2640").css({"position":"relative", "left":0, "top":0});
$("#2640").css({"width":"88px"});
$(".State > label").css({"position":"relative", "left":"-60px", "top":0});
$("#2641").css({"position":"relative", "left":"-116px", "top":0});
$("#2641").css({"width":"88px"});
$(".State > label").css({"left":"-121px"});
$("#2641").css({"left":"-161px", "width":98, "height":29});
$("#2637").css({"position":"relative", "left":"5px", "top":0});
$(".State > label").css({"left":"-109px"});
$("#2642").css({"width":"88px"});
$("#2643").css({"width":"88px"});
$(".Alternate_Phone").css({"left":"-129px"});
$(".State > label").css({"left":"-81px"});
$("#2643").css({"position":"relative", "left":"-32px", "top":0});
$(".UserAgreement label").css({"position":"relative", "left":0, "top":0, "width":419,         "height":77});
```

Into one line like this, while ONLY selecting lines with .css in it, nothing else:

`$('head').append("<style> #2626 { width: 300px; } #2627 { width: 300px; } #2626 {  width: 250px; height: 50px; } </style>");`

I need to be able to grab the first # element, all lines with .css, and then the variation, e.g. "width: 300px" and put it in the single line format like shown above.
I've been trying to do this using bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter filename:
read fname

echo "#######"
while read line;do

echo -n "\$('head').append(\"<style> "
awk -F "[)(]" '/.css/{printf "%s %s ",$2,$4}' $fname|sed 's/\"//g;s/,/;/g'
echo -n  "</style>\");"

done < $fname
echo "Total number of lines in file: $k"
```

Comment: Why is this tagged "python" if you said in your title that you want to use either bash or perl?

Comment: using python is also acceptable - sorry for the confusion!

Comment: where do they come from: #2626 { width: 250px; height: 50px; }

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
echo -n "\$('head').append(\"<style> "
awk -F "[)(]" '/.css/&&/#[0-9]+/{printf "%s %s ",$2,$4}' infile|sed 's/\"//g;s/,/;/g'
echo -n  "</style>\");"
```

result:

```
$('head').append("<style> #2626 {width:300px} #2627 {width:300px} #2628 {width:300px} #2629 {width:300px} #2631 {position:relative; left:-20px; top:0; width:128;   height:29} #2633 {width:300px} #2634 {width:300px} #2633 {} #2633 {position:relative; left:0; top:0; width:289; height:19} #2630 {position:relative; left:0; top:0; width:46; height:19} #2638 {width:300px} #2639 {width:300px} #2636 {position:relative; left:49; top:1} #2640 {position:relative; left:0; top:0} #2640 {width:88px} #2641 {position:relative; left:-116px; top:0} #2641 {width:88px} #2641 {left:-161px; width:98; height:29} #2637 {position:relative; left:5px; top:0} #2642 {width:88px} #2643 {width:88px} #2643 {position:relative; left:-32px; top:0} </style>");
```

Updated code:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
echo -n "\$('head').append(\"<style> "
awk -F "[)(]" '/.css/{printf "%s %s ",$2,$4}' infile|sed 's/\"//g;s/,/;/g'
echo -n  "</style>\");"
```

updated code #2:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter filename:
read fname

echo "#######"

echo -n "\$('head').append(\"<style> "
awk -F "[)(]" '/.css/{printf "%s %s ",$2,$4}' $fname|sed 's/\"//g;s/,/;/g'
echo -n  "</style>\");"
```

Comment: I'm getting this as the output:  
    $('head').append("<style> awk: can't open file infile
    source line number 1
    </style>");$('head').append("<style> awk: can't open file infile
    source line number 1
    </style>");$('head').append("<style> awk: can't open file infile
    source line number 1
    </style>");$('head').append("<style> awk: can't open file infile
    source line number 1
    </style>");$('head').append("<style> awk: can't open file infile

Comment: replace infile with your file name, infile is my test file name.

Comment: I think I might have it working for the simpler ones; #2626, #2627 and grabbing its operations - but what about the operations with more than one string?

$("#column-wide").css({"background-color":"#eff6f9"});
$("#2626").css({"width":"300px"});
$("#2627").css({"width":"300px"});
$("#2628").css({"width":"300px"});
$("#2629").css({"width":"300px"});
$(".Country > label").css({"position":"relative", "left":"-20px", "top":0});
$("#2631").css({"position":"relative", "left":"-20px", "top":0, "width":128, "height":29});

Comment: you need give all possible samples, and edit in original question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help BMW - I've added a majority of the file I need to parse - but it is still not all of it. I am going to make this a standardized script so I would love for it to be able to be future proof, regardless of what's being parsed (although it will always be the .css) No matter if I'm grabbing a class or id "#" or ".", or the number of operators "width:xx height:xx position, etc"

Comment: Almost there - I still need items like $(".Country > label").css({"position":"relative", "left":"-20px", "top":0}); to be parsed, not just the #xxxx. Also my script keeps looping for the amount of initial lines there are, anyway to stop that?

Comment: &&/#[0-9]+/ is used to search only #xxxx, remove them, you can see the rest.  for your second question, you need show us the initial lines, and the error output

Comment: Thank you BMW - I've re-edited what my script looks like now and it loops more than once? Is my read line wrong?

Comment: and I do need to add a ; at the end of each operator. e.g. $('head').append("<style> #2626 {width:300px}  to $('head').append("<style> #2626 {width:300px;}

Comment: You needn't put the input file in while loop, awk commmand will read it line by line directly. See my updated code #2.

Comment: BMW - you are a life saver! - I managed to get my initial script working but there is something I just learned that changes the game. For all of my ID's starting with a number (e.g. #234 #2345, etc) - they have to be changed to [id='234'] or [id='2345'] so that an example would look like $('head').append("<style> [id='2626'] {width:300px;} [id='2627'] {width:300px;} ONLY numerical ID's need to be changed, NOTHING Else. Can this be done!?